# How to represent uninitialized values in an int array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, nan

I have an `int` array that stores 5 integers. I intend to take 5 numbers as input and put them into the array in a sorted manner (ascending order). So basically, I'm putting the value, accepted at each step, at its position it should be in in ascending order. Assuming that no input is `0`, I have this code which works:

```
System.out.println("Enter 5 integers...");
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int[] arr = new int[5];
int c;

//assuming that no number entered is 0

for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
    c = sc.nextInt();
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        if(arr[j] == 0){ //placing an input where there's 0
            arr[j] = c;
            break;
        }
        else if(c < arr[j]){
            for(int k=4; k>j; k--)
                arr[k] = arr[k-1];
            arr[j] = c;
            break;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("The numbers in ascending order are\n"
                        +java.util.Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Basically I consider `0` as an invalid value and some other number (presumably non-zero) can be put in its place. I can take this for granted provided that the user does not enter `0`. But, WHAT IF THE USER ENTERS `0` (or any number for that matter)? I want to be able to place the numbers correctly including `0`. So I thought that I could use something else to represent **uninitialized** or **empty** spaces with something other than a number. I saw a post on SO where someone had a similar issue with a `double` array, so they could use `Double.NaN` to represent **invalid** or **empty** spaces. Unfortunately, JAVA doesn't have `Integer.NaN` so I couldn't use this trick.

So my question is, **How can I represent empty/uninitialized spaces in an int array?** Can something like `NaN` be used?

Comment: why don't you use an array of Integer? you can use null there.

other option would be to create a wrapper class that wraps your value with the status but this solution even sounds ugly

Comment: @pbielicki Although that didn't cross my mind, I was seeing if something like using `Double.NaN` could be done in this case, thus not having to use a wrapper class for a primitive type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you have an alternative to the "classical" way of bygone languages which would rely on a "magic value" to denote an uninitialised `int` (something like the largest or smallest possible value).

You can use `Integer`, rather than `int`, and use `null` for the "uninitialised" value:

`Integer[] arr = new Integer[5];`

Here, each element of `arr` is automatically initialised to `null`, which is nice.

But do then be aware of the dreaded `==` comparing references rather than values.

Comment: So this is the only way in case of integer, right? Nothing like using `Double.NaN` in `double` arrays can be done, right?

Comment: Even with range -128 to +127 you can only use `==` if the numbers were created using autoboxing or Integer.valueOf(). But if one of these integers was created with `new Integer(123)` then that one doesn't compare as equal with `==` to `Integer.valueOf(123)`, for example.

Comment: Yup that is a good point. I've removed my final sentence. Less is often more. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use some default value that you don't expect to be entered as a valid input (for example, a negative number such as `-1` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE` can work if all valid inputs are non-negative). This is the only way to go if you want to use an array of primitive integers (i.e. `int[]`).

Another way is to use an array of `Integer` (`Integer[]`), whose elements are initialized to `null` by default. Using wrapper types instead of primitives is considered less efficient, so there's a tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a separate array of `boolean` of the same length, and each entry with the same index as in the `int` array indicates whether the value was initialized or not:

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
boolean[] initialized = new boolean[arr.length];
int c;

//assuming that no number entered is 0

for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
    c = sc.nextInt();
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        if(!initialized[j]){ // use boolean array to find out if already initialized
            arr[j] = c;
            initialized[j] = true;
            break;
        }
        else if(c < arr[j]){
            for(int k=4; k>j; k--) {
                arr[k] = arr[k-1];
                initialized[k] = initialized[k-1];
            }
            arr[j] = c;
            initialized[j] = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is one way of doing it, considering that using wrappers instead of primitives is less sufficient. So +1. However, I'm more comfortable with @Bathsheba's answer right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> ***WHAT IF THE USER ENTERS 0?***

Then you need to:

- init the array with a negative number
- dont allow the user to give as
  input negative number (validate)

another opütion canbe use the wrapper clas Integer instead of the primitives, since those can easily prove against a null reference...

in my opinion not necesary in your case....

Comment: I assume that the user can enter anything, also a negative number, I just can't use a number to denote uninitialized values.